# Determine latest file based on datestamp in filename

Tags: powershell, date

I have a series of files in a directory with the following format:

```
file_ddMMyyyyhhttss.csv
```

eg:

```
myfile_151220171038.csv
myfile_301120171445.csv
myfile_121020161114.csv
```

I know how to select the latest by `LastWriteTime`:

```
gci "$pathtofile" | Sort LastWriteTime | Select -Last 1
```

but unsure how to split the "datestamp" in the file and then to sort by year, month and then date, in order to determine the latest file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the specific format in your file names prevents any useful sorting without parsing it, but you can do just that:

```
Get-ChildItem $pathtofile |
  ForEach-Object {
    # isolate the timestamp
    $time = $_ -replace '.*(\d{12}).*','$1'
    # parse
    $timestamp = [DateTime]::ParseExact($time, 'ddMMyyyyHHmm', $null)
    # add to the objects so we can sort
    $_ | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty Timestamp $timestamp
  } |
  Sort-Object Timestamp
```

Adjust to fit your exact date/time format, because the one you specified in your question does not match the one on your files.

Comment: Thanks. I quoted year, month and then date (and time which I forgot) as I thought this would be the logical order determining the latest version, despite the filename having the reverse order.

Comment: When running your script I get: Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "The DateTime represented by the string is not 
supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."

Comment: The exact format doesn't seem to fit what is in your file name. You can pass an array of supported formats to `ParseExact` to support different variants. The code above works for your example in the question, but I have no idea how the rest of your files look like.

Comment: `Sort-Object` can work with calculated properties, so you can do `Sort-Object @{n='Timestamp';e={[DateTime]::ParseExact(($_.Basename -replace '.*_(\d{14}).*', '$1'), 'ddMMyyyyHHmmss', [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)}}` without passing the objects through a `ForEach-Object` loop first.

Comment: @Ansgar, indeed. Although I tend to reserve excessively inlined code for golfing, not for instructional posts here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My proposition ;)
Only take file, only file with format asked, Only print file with date when date are really date.

```
 [System.DateTime]$parsedDate=get-date

 Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\" -file -filter "*.csv" | where BaseName -match ".*(\d{12}).*" | %{

   $DtString=$_.BaseName.substring($_.BaseName.Length - 12)

   if ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($DtString, "ddMMyyyyhhmm",$null,[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,[ref]$parseddate))
   {
       $_ | Add-Member -Name TimeInName -Value $parseddate -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru
   }

 } | Sort TimeInName -Descending | Select -First 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet can work not only with regular but also with [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx). That allows you to sort the files without passing them through a `ForEach-Object` loop first. Like this:

```
$pattern = '.*_(\d{14}).*'
$datefmt = 'ddMMyyyyHHmmss'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

Get-ChildItem $pathtofile | Sort-Object @{n='Timestamp';e={
    $datestr = $_.Basename -replace $pattern, '$1'
    [DateTime]::ParseExact($datestr, $datefmt, $culture)
}} | Select-Object -Last 1
```

I usually recommend using the `InvariantCulture` constant rather than `$null` as the third argument for `ParseExact()`, because using `$null` gave me errors in some cases.

If your source directory contains files that don't match your filename pattern you may want to exclude them with a `Where-Object` filter before sorting the rest:

```
Get-ChildItem $pathtofile | Where-Object {
    $_.Basename -match $pattern
} | Sort-Object @{n='Timestamp';e={
    $datestr = $_.Basename -replace $pattern, '$1'
    [DateTime]::ParseExact($datestr, $datefmt, $culture)
}} | Select-Object -Last 1
```